# Javascript Call Synchronous Function From External JS File

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a function in a .js file that takes information stored in localStorage and syncs them back to the server using synchronous ajax calls.  (Order of integration is vital, hence synchronous is necessary)

```
function syncUp() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("GET", "Default.aspx", true);  Also tried setting this to false
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xml.readyState == 4) {
         if (xml.status == 200) {
             var items = localStorage.getItem("SyncOrder");
             var sync = items.split(",");

             for (var i = 0; i < sync.length -1; i++) {
                 Perform repeated synchronous calls to webservice via AJAX to integrate each item to the server
              }
           }
        }
     }
  xml.send(null);
  }
```

syncUp() is being called from more than one place.  When called directly from the onclick event of a button where syncUp() is the only function called and the only code running, it works great.  However, if from a page where I am first adding an item to the localStorage object and then calling syncUp() as follows

```
function saveEdit(item) {
      var currData = localStorage.getItem("SyncOrder");
      localStorage["SyncOrder"] = currData + "," + item;
      syncUp();
}
```

, the xmlHTTPRequest status returns 0 and the sync doesn't perform. What could possibly be preventing the xmlHTTPRequest from getting a response of 200 as the only code running before syncUp() is a couple lines of javascript, which should be done executing before the site even gets into syncUp()?

Comment: Button onclick event.  Saves the edits made to that particular page in localStorage then tries to sync it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two causes of status code of zero.

1. Making calls from the file protocol.
2. The page is refreshing/navigating away as the request is being made.

In your case I would assume it is #2. If you are using a button or a link to make the Ajax call, make sure to cancel the click action with either `preventDefault` or `return false`.

Comment: Well now I just feel foolish.  Forgot to remove the location = location line I had in there to refresh the page from when I had all this structured differently.  Removed that and now all is fine.  Thanks so much!